# Order in positive series

Tags: sequences-and-series

While proving that the order doesn't matter when calculating the som of a positive serie I got the following problems.

Given $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}u_{n}^{}$ a positive convergent serie with sum s.
Let say that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}v_{n}^{}$ is the serie that we get when we change the order of the elements in the first serie.

The proof then starts with:

There is a bijection $ \sigma$ : $N_{0}^{} \longrightarrow N_{0}^{}$ so that $v_{i}^{} = u_{\sigma(i)}^{}$ and $u_{i}^{} = v_{\sigma_{}^{-1}(i)}^{}$

Write $s_{n}^{}$ and $t_{n}^{}$ for the n-th partial sum of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}u_{n}^{}$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}v_{n}^{}$

Choose n $\in N_{0}^{}$ and suppose $N(n) = \max\{\sigma(1),\sigma(2),\ldots,\sigma(n)\}$

Then we have:

$t_{n}{} = v_{1}+v_{2}+...+v_{n} = u_{\sigma(1)}+u_{\sigma(2)}+...+u_{\sigma(n)} \leqslant *** u_{1} + u_{2}+... + u_{N(n)} = S_{N(n)}$

My question:

*** is where I don't understand it. $\sigma$ is a bijection so is the max of the sigma's not just n? Why is less or equal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have **more** terms on the right: the notation "$\dots$" hides that, hence your confusion.

To see that it is possible: an example would be $\sigma\colon\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ defined by
$$
\sigma(n) = \begin{cases}
178 & \text { if } n=1\\
1 & \text { if } n=178\\
n & \text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

For instance, take $n=10$ with $\sigma$ as above, You have by definition $N(10)=\max(\sigma(1),\sigma(2),\dots,\sigma(10))  =\max(178,2,\dots,10) = 178$ .

Then, on the LHS, you have the $n=10$ terms $u_{\sigma(1)},\dots,u_{\sigma(n)}$, but on the RHS you have $N(n)=178$ terms: $u_{1},\dots,u_{178}$ (including, in particular, the 10 terms of the LHS).

Comment: I still don't get it, Since we just change the order of n terms. $\sigma (n)$ is always $\leqslant$ n. This means N(n) should also be less or equal to n isn't it?

Comment: No: $\sigma$ is not a permutation of the set $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, it is a permutation of the full set $\mathbb{N}$. So for a fixed $n$, you may have $\sigma(k) \gg n$ for some $1\leq k\leq n$ -- that is completely OK. (See the example given in my answer.)